# Using the same template for multiple sets each in its own table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm doing some experimenting with CakePHP and I came across the following:

Take users, each user is in a specific state (f.e. inactive, banned, new, ...). Each user has only one of these states.

Now apart from this state all users are part of the same Model (Users).
So their visual representation in a template with a html table is exactly the same.

What I want to do now is putting all the users in the same state in the same table. Having a different table for each state.

It looks silly to go around and repeating the same template code for each set of users.

What's the proper way to handle this in CakePHP 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a different table for each set, then an element might be the way to do. Or simply wrap the entire table in a `foreach ($states as $state)` in your view. Either are easily done.

But I'd suggest that perhaps what you want is really to put them all in one table with subheadings? That way, the columns will all be the same width for each state. To do that, I'd have all the users in a single query result, ordered by state (and then name, or whatever is helpful), and then as you loop through them, you check to see whether the state is different than it was for the last user, and if so output an extra line with `<th colspan="x"><?= $user->state ?></th>` or some such.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and giving multiple solutions. Just tried the suggestion to make a giant loop over the table. This would probably "break" (or at least affect) the paginator right? So if only 10 items of a total 30 are shown you might only see 5 typeA, 4 typeB and 1 typeC (while there are still more typeC). So it might get confusing to the user by seeing a table with only one entry.

Comment: Seems like perhaps less potential for confusion if you put it all in one table with subheadings, but this is always going to be a potential situation when you are paginating, regardless of what option you use for displaying them.

Comment: In the case of making a seperate result set for each that wouldn't be the case I think. I'll try it like that as well.Or will setting multiple list variables (1 for type a, 1 for type b, ...) with the same Entity class give problems?

Comment: If you're making a separate result set for each group, then it's not really pagination any more, is it? If you have 5 users in state a and 50 in state b, and you limit it to 10 per page, then what do you envision being shown for state a on page 2? This can get complicated quickly. Most common solution is to include them all in one paginated result set, which can be re-sorted by state or name using Cake's default baked code, or else have entirely separate URLs for each state.